# Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(\nabla\times H) = \nabla \times \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$?

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

While trying to prove a particular equation using Maxwell's equations in electromagnetic theory, there is a step in my textbook that says

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(\nabla\times H) = \nabla \times \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$$

Why is this true? Is it because of the Clairaut's theorem on partial derivatives?

Comment: Curl acts on space variables, so you should be able to pass the time derivative through. When in doubt, use definitions.